# Tensor product of two ideals/ Projective module?

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, ideals, tensor-products, projective-module

Suppose $R$ is a commutative ring with unity and $I, J$ be two ideals of R with the property that $R\simeq  I\otimes_R J$ as an $R$-modules. How can I show that $I$ is a projective $R$-module?

For me, this seems like a blend of all concepts that I have learned so far in module theory and couldn't think of a way to solve this question. Can any one give me a solution with an explanation of whats happening here. Thanks for anything you can provide on this.

Comment: Projective modules are direct summands of free modules.

Comment: @Bernard: Tensor product is a free $R$-module mod-out by some relations. So how can still it be a free $R$-module?

Comment: @Bumblebee: Every module (free modules are no exception) is isomorphic to a quotient module; e.g. $M \cong M/0$. Every module is even isomorphic to a nontrivial quotient; e.g. $M \cong (M \times N) / (0 \times N)$.

Comment: Sorry: I had misread the hypothesis as $R\simeq I\oplus J$. I'll remove my comments. That being said, a quotient of a free module can perfectly be free.

Comment: @Hurkyl: I still can not understand how your hint helps me to escape from this Jungle.

Comment: @Bumblebee: My comment is meant to dispel your apparent misconception that "a free module mod-out by some relations" cannot be a free module.

Comment: @Hurkyl: Thank you for your clarification. At the beginning I was thinking about $\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}.$

Comment: There could be a wide variety of ways to prove this with varying degrees of difficulty and abstraction. If the answers and hints aren’t helping much it might be good to add some of the definitions you are using (are you using the categorical lifting definition of projective?) and maybe some of your thoughts so we know what kind of tools and proofs will be useful for where you’re at in your studies

Comment: Addendum: may also be good to mention the extent to which you are content with a category theoretic proof

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that  $R \cong I \otimes_R J$ implies that the functor $R\textrm{-}\mathbf{Mod} \to R\textrm{-}\mathbf{Mod}$ given by $I \otimes_R -$ is a category equivalence, since an inverse up to natural equivalence is given by $J \otimes_R-$.

In particular, $I \otimes_R -$ commutes with all limits, so it is exact, thus $I$ is flat as an $R$-module.

There's also a theorem that says that a module $M$ is finitely presented iff $M \otimes_R -$ commutes with infinite products, thus in our case $I$ is finitely presented.

Finally, finitely presented flat modules are projective.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a more elementary solution. I recommend you draw the diagrams.

Let $p: M\to N$ be an epimorphism and $f: I\to N$ a morphism. We want to lift $f$ to $g: I\to M$. Let $l: R\to I\otimes J$ be an isomorphism.

We get $f\otimes id_J : I\otimes J\to N\otimes J$, and so composing with our isomorphism $l$ we get $m=k\circ(f\otimes id_J)\circ l : R\to J\otimes N$, where $k : N\otimes J\to J\otimes N$ is the canonical isomorphism.

Now $p$ "restricts" to $q= id_J\otimes p: J\otimes M \to J\otimes N$ which is still an epimorphism and since $R$ is projective (it's free !)   we may lift $m$ to $n: R\to J\otimes M$ with $q\circ n = m$.

Final step : tensor with $I$ to get $id_I\otimes n : I\otimes R \to I\otimes (J\otimes M)$. Let $s: I\otimes J\otimes M \to M$ be the natural isomorphism induced by $l$ and the natural isomorphism $R\otimes M\to M$; let $t: I\to I\otimes R$ be the natural isomorphism.

Put $g= s\circ (id_I\otimes n)\circ t$. You may now check that $g$ works using the different naturality conditions : write down the diagrams and it will be clear.